# how to display an array element wise in a component of React js?

Tags: reactjs, dynamic-arrays

Hi I have a response coming from an API as a JSON ["a","b","c"].
I want to display this json Element Wise in a React Component. I have converted the JSON into array.
I am able to display the whole JSON and array as a whole on the component but not able to display it element wise.

In javascript i used to put a for loop and display all element by document.write but I want to know how to do so in REACT JS.

Comment: The same way: loop through it and create elements.

Comment: Please read the documentation: [Lists and Keys](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the render() function:

```
<ul>
{yourArray.map((item,index) => 
    <li key={index}>{item}</li>
)}
</ul>
```

Is this what you want to do?

Comment: @Jyoti2994 [Facebook recommends avoiding the use of indices as `key` values if the items can reorder](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys), so you may want to try to figure out another `key` for each item if that's the case here.

Comment: i always got an error Cannot read property 'map' of undefined am new bie :)

now am following tutorial in udemy but still don't know how to solved it

Comment: @FreddySidauruk The reason for this error is that  react got an undefined when it expect an Array to map. The property 'array' may has not been initialized when the 'render()' of component was called. Did you fetch the 'array' data asyn? try to give 'array' and initial value '[]' to avoid this error